# Linux Kernel Driver: Returning a pointer to a kfifo results in a null pointer

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've come up against a problem passing a pointer to a kfifo that I can't seem to solve.

A little background; I've taken over the development a of Kernel Driver for a Gumstix interface with an FPGA. The FPGA in this scenario is basically taking multiple serial streams, doing some processing on the data and then making it available to the Gumstix via the GPIO. Since this is actually quite a complex project, I'll spare the details - since it would turn into quite a lengthly post, of mostly irrelevant information. I have working prototype drivers for the individual serial interfaces - this driver is just all of those combined.

In the first / main file (gpio.c) of this driver a number of kfifo's are initialised and stored in an array, in a structure:

```
#define NUM_DEVICES 31
#define DEVICE_FIFO_SIZE 65536

struct fpga_interface {
    ...
    struct kfifo fifos[NUM_DEVICES];
    spinlock_t fifo_locks[NUM_DEVICES];
    ...
};

static struct fpga_interface fpga;

int __init fpga_init_interface(void)
{
    int i;

    info("Initialising\n");

    // KFifo initialisation
    for(i=0; i<NUM_DEVICES; i++)
    {
        if(kfifo_alloc(&(fpga.fifos[i]), DEVICE_FIFO_SIZE, GFP_KERNEL)) {
            printk(KERN_ERR, "Error allocating the KFIFOs\n");
            return 1;
        }

        spin_lock_init(&fpga.fifo_locks[i]);

        info("Initialised KFIFO %d with addr=%x\n", i, &(fpga.fifos[i]));
    }
    ...
    info("Initialised\n");
}

void get_fifo(int dev, struct kfifo* fifo, spinlock_t* lock)
{
    fifo = &(fpga.fifos[dev]);
    lock = &(fpga.fifo_locks[dev]);

    info("Returning the KFIFO for devid=%d, fifo=%x, lock=%x", dev, fifo, lock);
}
```

Then in another file (primary.c - which deals a specific interface) we have this:

```
struct fpga_primary {
    ....
    struct kfifo* fifo;
    spinlock_t* fifo_lock;
...
};

static struct fpga_primary primary;

int fpga_primary_init(void)
{
    info("Starting Primary\n");

    //Get our fifo and fifo lock
    get_fifo(1, primary.fifo, primary.lock_fifo);

    info("Got kfifo_addr=%x, lock_addr=%x\n", primary.fifo, primary.fifo_lock);
    ...
    info("Completed Primary\n");
}
```

Now, below is the kernel log from the gumstix:

```
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17837.989776] GPIO: Initialising
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17837.997497] Initialised KFIFO 0 with addr=bf062bb4
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.005249] Initialised KFIFO 1 with addr=bf062bc8
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.012847] Initialised KFIFO 2 with addr=bf062bdc
...
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.233947] GPIO: Initialised
...
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.264984] PRIMARY: Starting Primary
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.272979] GPIO: Returning the KFIFO for devid=1, fifo=bf062bc8, lock=bf062e20
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.281280] PRIMARY: Got kfifo_addr=0, lock_addr=0
Nov 30 02:28:14 overo [17838.296203] PRIMARY: Completed Primary
```

What you'll notice is that the call to get_fifo(...) returns NULL pointers. Which is not good really and I can't seem to find out why.

I'm using the OpenEmbedded / BitBake standard environment, with Kernel version 3.2.0 and Angstrom 2011.03 tool chain. I'm building on Ubuntu 10.04.

Any ideas? I'm left thinking that for some reason I'm being prevented from passing a pointer to the kfifo around...but I've not been able to find anything documented as to why I can't / shouldn't do this, considering we pass pointers to kfifo's along to the kifo_ functions.

Comment: How does `get_fifo()` return values?  It needs a double pointer to *write back* the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the wrong result is due to the function void get_fifo(int dev, struct kfifo* fifo, spinlock_t* lock), in this function, you assign the results to local variables: fifo and lock; when the get_fifo() return, the local variable will be invalid.

So my suggestion is: declare the get_fifo() function as:

```
    void get_fifo(int dev, struct kfifo** fifo, spinlock_t** lock)
    {
        *fifo = &(fpga.fifos[dev]);
        *lock = &(fpga.fifo_locks[dev]);

        info("Returning the KFIFO for devid=%d, fifo=%x, lock=%x", dev, *fifo, *lock);
    }
```

In function int fpga_primary_init(void), call get_fifo() as:

```
    get_fifo(1, &(primary.fifo), &(primary.lock_fifo));
```

I think it will solve your problem.